# Creating and Using a Skewed Gaussian Distribution in Matlab

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, skewness

I am very new to matlab, and only used it to do some fairly basic math to visualize a method. Here is an example of what I've done with a normal distribution:

```
mu = 2;         
sigma = 4;     

x = linspace(-5, 5, 1000);

pdf_values = normpdf(x, mu, sigma);

% boundaries:

p1 = 0.01;      
p2 = 0.99;      

b1 = norminv(p1, mu, sigma) + 0.001 ;
b2 = norminv(p2, mu, sigma);
m1 = (b1 + b2)/2;

prob_below = normcdf(m1, mu, sigma) - normcdf(b1, mu, sigma);
prob_above = normcdf(b2, mu, sigma) - normcdf(m1, mu, sigma);


if prob_below > prob_above
    m2 = (m1 + b1) / 2;
    median =  (m1 + m2)/2;
elseif prob_above > prob_below
    m2 = (m1 + b2) / 2;
    median =  (m1 + m2)/2;
else
    % choose randomly
    m2 = datasample([(m1 + b1) / 2, (m1 + b2) / 2], 1);
    median =  (m1 + m2)/2;
end
```

Now I am trying to do the same but using a skewed distribution. I have tried almost everything I've seen online but am constantly hitting some roadblock.

```
mu4 = 5;
sigma4 = 1;
skew4 = 5;
kurt4 = 1;
x4 = linspace(-5,15,100);
[p4,type4] = pearspdf(x4,mu4,sigma4,skew4,kurt4);
c4 = pearscdf(x4,mu4,sigma4,skew4,kurt4);
r4 = pearsrnd(mu4,sigma4,skew4,kurt4,[100,1]);



figure;
plot(x4, p4, 'LineWidth', 2);
title('Pearson Distribution Type 4 PDF');
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Probability Density');
grid on;
```

If I use this I am not even able to see the graph. Is there a way to create a skewed normal distribution and just use basic cdf, inv, and pdf math functions with it? Or do I have to write a new function?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Two comments: (1) The normal distribution has no skew, so you would need to explain what you mean by a "skewed normal distribution". (2) CV is for statistics questions, and anything that is exclusively about programming is off-topic here. You can flag your question for migration to StackOverflow if you are mainly asking about the coding aspects. (But then please first edit your post to focus on this, just as if you are mainly asking about statistics, it would be good if you could edit for that.)

Comment: It's unclear what your initial code is intended to do.  It's always better to *describe it in English* in case it does not carry out the calculations you believe it should!